# How can I annotate an untyped import?

Tags: python, import, python-typing

I'd like to add type annotations to an untyped import. How should I do that? This does not work:

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, cast, reveal_type
from funcy import retry

# bug.py:5: note: Revealed type is "Any"
reveal_type(retry)

F = TypeVar("F", bound=Callable)
retry = cast(Callable[..., Callable[[F], F]], retry)

# bug.py:11: note: Revealed type is "Any"
reveal_type(retry)
```

Since I do not assign `retry` here, but I import it, I am unsure which notation allows me to annotation on import. This does not work:

```
from funcy import retry : Callable[..., Callable[[F], F]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an annotation for a name before defining the name for the first time:

```
retry: Callable[..., Callable[[F], F]]
from funcy import retry
```

---

Your attempted solution using `cast` did not work because you assigned the result to the original name which already was associated with a type (the type checker saw an assignment of a `Callable[..., Callable[[F], F]]` to a variable of type `Any` and said "okay, this is allowed", but that does not narrow the type of the variable).

You could have used a temporary name for the import and then assigned the result of `cast` to the desired name:

```
from funcy import retry as _retry

retry = cast(Callable[..., Callable[[F], F]], _retry)
```

Comment: +1 for the temporary name idea. I had tried (and disliked) the cast to `_retry`, but importing and `_retry` and casting to `retry` is great.

Comment: The first solution gives me `error: Name "retry" already defined on line 3  [no-redef]`

Comment: You get that error if you write the annotation after the variable has already been defined. You have to write the annotation first.

Comment: I did. I still get the error: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=ab17011f24fa67db28b84bd3bdb7c02d

Comment: That looks like a follow-up error for the import error. A working example: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=3ad827f566ec4957f42b411c2fa86adb

Comment: `math.cos` is already typed (without any additional annotation), and that is probably why your code works. Compare https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=a7be0897e3235f3b461679b89af5f6dd. My question is how to "annotate an **untyped** import".

Comment: It also works when doing an untyped import, but I can't demonstrate that on mypy-play.net because I can't create a custom separate file to import.

Comment: Here's a way to demonstrate it using sh: `echo -e 'from typing import Any\nx: Any' >a.py; echo -e 'x: int\nfrom a import x\nreveal_type(x)' >b.py; mypy b.py`, output: `b.py:3: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"`

Comment: You are right! So clearly `a.x` and `funcy.retry` behave differently - I wonder why that is.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15170.